# Integration on f(-x)

Tags: integration, functions

Suppose that for some function $f(x)$ such that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)$ exists, then will that necessarily imply that 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(-x)?$$

Comment: f(-x) is the reflection of f(x) about the y axis. Can you see why now, by the definition of a definite integral, why the two must be equal?

Comment: Consider $y=f(x)= \log(x) $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that
$$\int_{-a}^{a}f(x)\mathrm{d}x=\int_{a}^{-a}f(-x)\mathrm{d}(-x)=\int_{-a}^{a}f(-x)\mathrm{d}x$$
And take the limits. It will imply that the integral of $f(-x)$ is the same as the integral of $f(x)$, if it exists. Can you prove that it exists?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a more intuitive way of thinking about this:

Consider $g(x):=f(x)-f(-x)$, then $g(-x)=f(-x)-f(x)=-g(-x)$, then:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)-f(-x) dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x)dx=0$$since $g(x)$ is odd. 
Hence $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(-x)     dx$

(P.S. I did not intend to argue in a very rigorous way)